# file_put_contents does not work when run through cronjob

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

On my server i have a php file that i need to run daily, it will make about 300 php files, (replaces the current one)
this file works fine, except when run through a cronjob, then the files do not get created.

I have narrowed down the location when the error happens, but i have no idea why, or how to fix it.
i would like to say again, the script works fine when called from my browser. (but doing it by wget is not a option due to security)

It think it has something to do with 'require_once', or the pathing

3 versions:

version 1: file does not get created at all, rest of the script does not execute either

```
<?php 
require_once('wp-load.php');require_once('wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
file_put_contents('/path/file.php',"testcontents");
?>
```

Version 2, file gets created, but rest of the script does not execute

```
<?php 
file_put_contents('/path/file.php',"testcontents");
require_once('wp-load.php');require_once('wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
?>
```

Version 3:  the file gets executed fine, but file_put_contents is not included, and it is something i do need, so it only does half the job atm.

```
<?php 
require_once('wp-load.php');require_once('wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
?>
```

again, the issue is only around when the script is called as a cronjob, i do not have root access to the server (just cpanel access), it works fine on other servers we have.

edit:
test1.php gets created
test.2php does NOT get created

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
file_put_contents('/home/username/public_html/visit/test1.php',"test1");
require_once('wp-load.php');
file_put_contents('/home/username/public_html/visit/test2.php',"test2");

?>
```

Comment: Your cronjob should probably have an absolute file path for all path references, rather than any relative file path, just to be sure to rule out a filepathing issue. Also where is the cron saved? If you have multiple servers you really should have WHM access to at least one server rather than limited CPanel access.

Comment: Can you confirm your file being run as a cronjob does not create any **error logs**?

Comment: there is no errorlog (well, there was 1, but unrelated and fixed since)
for all our bigger projects we have whm, on all of these it works perfectly fine, without issues.
on this cheap hosting, it doesnt work when run through the cron, i already tried with absolute pathing aswell

Comment: Sorry, to go over this but I want to be absolutely clear: So you are sure that the cronjob does run, and it works correctly without any error unless it contains`file_put_contents` where the PHP script fails. Where *exactly* are you putting the files?

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue that PHP (or whoever the account user is that runs the cronjob) is not authorised to generate new files in the location specified. You could try to increase your error detection level (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`) on the cronjob script to show everything that's detected as imperfect.

Comment: It seems i have made a mistake somewhere, (i was sure the rest of the script ran) but it seems some part of the script (or all) was cached, which caused that, so it seems to break on the require_once atm

Comment: Remember that cronjob files do not have access to `$_SERVER` data values and so can't be very smart finding files. Therefore any external file reference needs to be absolutely pathed as mentioned before, currently `wp-load.php` needs to be in the same directory as the script *and needs to not reference any `$_SERVER` values*

Comment: still can't seem to get it to load properly, wp-load.php  is in the same folder as the script beeing called (both are in public_html), i no longer use any $_server calls
(file still works fine when calling it by my browser)

Comment: And still nothing at all on the error logs for the cronjob even with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` set ?

Comment: Checking obvious stuff, but does the directory you're trying to write to with `file_put_contents` exist and have write permission set on it?

Comment: i have edited my answer,  the error log is clean still with error_reporting(e_all) set.
i changed the pathing on purpose just now (to make it wrong) and that showed up in the error log,  but the way its set normally produces no errors

Comment: Yeh, the folder exists and i can write to it (when i call the file in my browser, everything works fine)
in my edited answer
test1.php gets created
test2.php does not get created

Comment: Then it looks like the issue is in `wp-load.php` , perhaps you can check what parts of wp-load are actually *needed*  by the cronjob script and paste them directly into the script and avoid that `require` statement?

Comment: It seems you were correct, in wp-load.php  the 
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php';
breaks it,  no idea why, or how to resolve that yet though... XD

Comment: As said, Wordpress is not designed to be called from the command line, something in there is making a call or a check with `$_SERVER` or is using a similar variable that PHP does not use on command line calls. As said above, best bet would be to check what (if any) Wordpress functionality you need and import that action directly into your cronjob file, but I suspect you don't actually *need* any wordpress functions in your cronjob

Comment: See if you can use `wp-cron` on your Wordpress settings to simulate a cronjob to build the `file_put_cocaine()` script, reference:  https://wetopi.com/how-to-run-a-cron-job-with-wordpress/

Comment: thnx for all the help, i really appreciate it. i will have a proper look at that tommorrow
(stupid thing is, it works fine on my dedicated servers) making be believe its a server setting/issue somehow.
i am still new to php, for the script i loop through all pages on the website, and make a file with info from those pages. thats probably possible without wordpress functions,  but i have no idea how :P

Comment: Sure, no worries. If the issue is the `file_put_contents` rather than an incidental WP stuff, the best bet would be to look up the [**Cpanel Logs**](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/The+cPanel+Log+Files) and search through them for any indicators as to why it's being blocked. Then you can try running the cronjob as another user who does have the correct permissions or `chmod`ing the appropriate filepath to allow writing to that path by that user.  Good luck.